# 1px black line at the top and bottom of app screen for iPhone 6 and iPhone 6 Plus

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode, ios-simulator

This is a very strange issue. Happening both in the simulator AND on iPhone 6 and 6 Plus devices.

I am getting a 1px black line at the very top and very bottom of every page of my app. It is just above the status bar at the top and it is not just when there is a nav bar. It is on every page, even when it is too hard to see, I screenshot the page and zoom and can see the thin black lines at the top and bottom.

Black line at the top:
[image: Here is the black line at the top]
Black line at the bottom:
[image: Here is the black line at the bottom]

Comment: Is it seen only in your app or it also seen in the other apps.

Comment: put Default images for iPhone 6 & 6 plus in ImageXCassets.

Comment: Have you checked that, this appear in Simulator only, May be device doesn't have this problem.

Comment: check constraints if you've set any? maybe you've sent the view to be -1px?

Comment: @All : this is happening because his app is not made for iPhone 6 & 6 Plus. So what he see is iPhone 5s app on those devices. When you see old apps on new devices, you will see 1px difference because those apps are zoomed...

Comment: Thanks @FahimParkar, you might be right. We only have 1x and 2x images in our assets folder. Are you saying that once we have added all of our 3x images the app will act as it should on iPhone 6 and 6 Plus? That is all that is needed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is happening because your app is not compatible with iPhone 6 & 6 Plus.

What you see is zoomed version of iPhone 5 on iPhone 6 & 6 Plus.

You have to make app compatible to iPhone 6 & 6 Plus screens by using Auto-Layout.

Comment: I have created app with autolayout. still its showing line on top and bottom(1px).. no idea whats happening.

Comment: you have default images for iphone 6 & 6 plus?

Comment: yes i have all the images required... Please suggest what can i do.